# HTMLAgilityPack Add to end of script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I need to use HTMLAgilityPack to add a line into `jQuery(document).ready` of something like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $...
        });
    </script>
```

How can I select that specific node?

Comment: I didn't think the html-agility-pack was meant to inject code, only provide a way for HTML query based XPath expressions.

Comment: You can find your script node with HtmlAgilityPack, but then you'll have to work with strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In respond to updated question, to find the `<script>` tag containing javascript code, you can try using this XPath :

```
//script[@type='text/javascript']
```

or if you need to also make sure javascript code within that tag has `jQuery(document).ready` part :

```
//script[@type='text/javascript' and contains(.,'jQuery(document).ready')]
```